# Ints or doubles when modelling random events

Tags: random

Theoretically, if I want to model an event in which the probability is 50%, I could merely generate a Boolean and do the event if it returned true, for example.

Now, this could also be achieved by generating a random double, between 0 and 100 (inclusive) and do the event if the number is greater than 50.

Theoretically, both these solutions would work. However, in practice, I know that random number generators are in fact pseudo random number generators, and that this is a somewhat complex topic.

Nonetheless, I'd like to know what are the implications, if any, of implementing one method or the other.

Comment: This would likely depend on the generator used. You could test the "implications" by generating a large amount of data from each way and analyzing frequencies.

Comment: For reference, do you know if someone already made such study? If so, could you link it?

Comment: I don't, but this is fairly trivial to do small scale. I've done this before to test the distribution of my own random functions. In Clojure it's like maybe 5 lines. In a language like Java, it would be a little more, but conceptually it would still be quite straightforward. I might be able to whip something up when I get home, but that wouldn't be for several hours.

Comment: In that case, I can try to do it. Nonetheless, I wouldn't know exactly how to judge how "good" the results are. I know the results shouldn't be exactly 50% in both case, but I don't know how far they can go and still be reasonable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, if the only use of random numbers in the program is to [model N in M chances](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Boolean_True_False_Conditions), then random integers are better than random floating-point numbers.  There are many reasons for this.

- Computers can represent integers more naturally than floating-point numbers.
- Pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) algorithms that generate integers are more portable and are easier to make deterministic.  In fact, many popular PRNGs, including Mersenne Twister and linear congruential generators, output N-bit integer values, not floating-point numbers.
- Generating random floating-point numbers in computers depends on generating random integers, not the other way around.
- Floating-point implementations and floating-point math vary in subtle ways between computer platforms and operating systems, and sometimes in nondeterministic or inconsistent ways.  This is bad for applications that care about using repeatable "random" numbers.  See "[Floating Point and IEEE 754 Compliance for NVIDIA GPUs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/floating-point/)" for a fuller discussion.
- There are many subtle points involving comparison of floating-point numbers and converting random floating-point numbers to integers.  For example, take the idiom `RNDU01() < 0.1`, which is true one tenth of the time.  `RNDU01()` is a random number in [0, 1).  There are [many ways to implement `RNDU01()`](http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it/#remarks), such as by dividing a 32 bit number by `2^32`, a 53-bit number by `2^53`, normalizing a huge integer, and so on.  In addition, `0.1` is not always representable as `0.1` in common floating-point number formats.  As another example, the JavaScript idiom `Math.floor(Math.random()*N)` for generating a random integer in [0, N) can also go wrong in [several subtle ways](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Note3).